# can't access database in android device

Tags: codenameone

Here is the code I used to create database for the application. I put this code in `init(Object context)` method.

```
 boolean created = Database.exists("MyDB.db");
            db = Database.openOrCreate("MyDB.db");
            if(db == null){
                System.out.println("SQLite is not supported on this platform");
                return;
            }
            if (!created) {
                db.execute("create table temp (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name text,num double);");
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    db.execute("insert into temp (name,num) values (?,?);", new String[]{users[i], "" + ages[i]});
                }
            }
```

In simulator it is working fine. I can fetch data from database and perform CRUD operation. But when installed the application on android device its not working. I don't know even if database is creating or not.

I tried another example. Here is the code.

```
try {
            boolean isExist = Database.exists("hx.db");
            db = Database.openOrCreate("hx.db");
            if(db == null) {
                System.out.println("SQLite is not supported on this platform");
                return;
            }

            if(!isExist) {
                db.execute("create table variable_type( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, varType TEXT);");
                for(int i = 0; i< variable_type.length; i++ ) {
                    db.execute("insert into variable_type( id, varType) values (?, ?);", new String[]{null, variable_type[i]});
                }
                db.execute("create table uom( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, varType TEXT, uom TEXT, uom_system TEXT );");
                for(int i = 0; i < uom.length -1; i++) {
                    db.execute("insert into uom( id, varType, uom, uom_system) values (?, ?, ?, ?);", new String[]{null, uom[0], uom[i+1], "NA"});
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Below method used to fetch data.

```
 public List<String> getUnitTypes() {
        List<String> unitTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            if(Database.exists("hx.db"))
                db = Database.openOrCreate("hx.db");

            Cursor cursor = db.executeQuery("select * from uom;");
            while(cursor.next()) {
                Row r = cursor.getRow();
                unitTypes.add(r.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in reading values;");
        }
        return unitTypes;
    }
```

Here is my form where i'm using `getUnitTypes()` method.

```
    import java.util.List;
    import com.codename1.ui.ComboBox;
    .....
    private ComboBox<String> in_dropdown, out_dropdown ;
    private List<String> unitTypes ;
    .......
    public TemperatureConversion() {


    in_dropdown = new ComboBox<String>();
    in_dropdown.setCommandList(true);
    in_dropdown.addActionListener(unitChangeListener);

    out_dropdown = new ComboBox<String>();
    out_dropdown.setCommandList(true);
    out_dropdown.addActionListener(unitChangeListener);

    unitTypes = AppController.getUnitTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < unitTypes.size(); i++) {
        out_dropdown.addItem(unitTypes.get(i));
        in_dropdown.addItem(unitTypes.get(i));
    }
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the code from SQLDemo which is running fine on Android devices. The only thing I can spot as a difference is that you used the `init(Object)` method whereas SQLDemo used the `start()` method. But I don't think that should cause a problem.

In what way isn't the application working? Does it fail to launch?

I suggest moving the code to the `start()` method wrapping everything that is suspect in try/catch and placing a label with the error into the form in case of an exception.

Comment: Application is not crashing, just one form where I used values from database in drop down list.

Comment: Simulator is showing correctly. There isn't any exception. I can see the database in desktop. But how do I confirm that database is created in mobile device?

Comment: Just use the exist method in that form and log to the screen or using the Log API. I doubt the snippet initially posted is related to the issue.

Comment: Its possible that the fact that uom is both the table name and a column name is problematic on Android.

Comment: I get that database is working fine after renaming uom column but still having trouble with fetching data. I am using `getUnitTypes()` method to do so. Working fine with the simulator but not showing in mobile device. I printed the values on label, its not showing in mobile device.

Comment: `getUnitTypes()` method is problematic but don't know why not working.

Comment: Is it possible that you are opening the database more than once without closing it?

Comment: I get the problem. `null` in this statement `db.execute("insert into uom( id, varType, uom, uom_system) values (?, ?, ?, ?);", new String[]{null, uom[0], uom[i+1], "NA"});`
, that was working in simulator.

Comment: I don't think you can set null to a primary key on SQLite in a portable way

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason at last.
It seems database loading time issue.
I tried SQLite for each version of Android.
It was successful only same or higher version of API Level 24.
For usage of lower version, you need to install db in proper moment.

> **Hint: Please install db when should be invoked, and NEVER use `init()` or `start()` method to install db for lower version of Android.**

Instead, you may use `actionListener()` of Button or something else.

This should work~!